# How to select all links whose protocol is not http with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Suppose that you have:

```
<a href="file://...">link1</a>
<a href="file://...">link2</a>
<a href="http://...">link3</a>
<a href="http://...">link4</a>
```

What code should I use to select only link1 and link2 without using `a[href^=http]`?

Comment: You've identified the solution, how come you don't want to use it?

Comment: if I used a[href^=http] means, i would get only link3 and link4
and do not want to use 

a[href^file://]

Comment: I have tried this a:not[href^=http]
but it does not work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's exactly how you would do it:

```
$('a:not(a[href^=http])')
```

or

```
$('a[href^=file]')
```

What's wrong with selecting based on the href attribute?

Comment: @MattBall, it's just a matter of testing and learning.
Thanks so much

Comment: You have to read the jQuery selector API very carefully; every character matters. For instance, `$('a:not(a [href^=http])')` won't work.

Comment: I just tested it as well, and it works for me. I copy-and-pasted the first method I suggested. Are you not using the latest version of jQuery?

Comment: I was using jquery 1.2... now i changed to use 1.3 and it works now